# PHP array_merge_recursive using foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, array-merge

I want to merge a few array into a new array, but group them by the same key value

When I use this loop

```
foreach($mrh as $group){
    print_r($group);
};
```

Out put is

```
Array (
    [2] => 4
)
Array (
    [2] => 5
)
Array (
    [3] => 7
)
Array (
    [3] => 8
)
Array (
    [3] => 10
)
```

My desired output is

```
array (
    [2] => array(
        [0] => 4,
        [1] => 5
    ),
    [3] => array(
        [0] => 7,
        [1] => 8,
        [2] => 10,
    )
)
```

`array_merge_recursive()` may be useful, but i cant solve it with an `foreach` loop

Answer (score 1):

Simply loop the array, and with an inner loop, process the inner elements. Then assign them into the resulting array based on their key.

```php
$result = [];
foreach ($mrh as $group) {
    foreach ($group as $key=>$value) {
        // Declare the array if it does not exist, to avoid notices
        if (!isset($result[$key]))
            $result[$key] = [];

        // Append the value
        $result[$key][] = $value;
    }
}
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/NeECu

Answer (score 1):

If your inner array is **always** on size 1 you can use [array-key-first](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-first.php) as:

```
foreach($mrh as $e) {
    $k = array_key_first($e);
    $res[$k][] = $e[$k];
}
```

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/H20VB)

Comment: Neat way of going about it, I like it!

Answer (score 0):

```
$mrh = [ [2=>4], [2=>5], [3=>7], [3=>8], [3=>10] ];
$newArray = [];

foreach($mrh as $group){ // loop over groups
  foreach($group as $key => $value) { // “loop over” group, to get access to key and value
    $newArray[$key][] = $value; // add value as a new element in the sub-array accessed by $key
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using `foreach`

```
 $a = [
[2 => 4],
[2 => 5],
[3 => 7],
[3 => 8],
[3 => 10]
];
$r = [];
foreach($a as $k => $v){
  $_value = end($v);
  $r[key($v)][] = $_value;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($r);
```